# Young Adult Sci-fi book about cyber-terrorists

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

I read it probably in the mid 1990's. The book involves a group of anonymous terrorists who attack people over the internet, usually in virtual reality simulations. One scene that stands out the most to me is when they use machine guns in a simulation of Babe Ruth calling his home run. A teenage boy goes undercover in their organization to try to find out who they are.

That's basically all I remember of the book. Does anyone know the title?

Answer (score 3):

This is likely one of Tom Clancy's *Net Force Explorers* books, specifically *[Virtual Vandals](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0425161730)*.

[image]

> While watching a holographic "old-timers" baseball game, Net Force Explorer Matt Hunter, and several of his Net Force Explorer friends are filled with excitement at seeing the legendary Babe Ruth come up to bat, but while doing his well-known routine of pointing to the stands, a group of four people dressed in outfits from the 30's, stand up and open fire on the entire stadium with Tommy guns. Everyone knows that virtual bullets can kill you, and Matt and his Net Force Explorer friends know that this group of vandals must be stopped. But the stadium shoot-out is just the beginning. Now Matt and his friends are worried that perhaps even the legenday Net Force Explorers will be unable to stop them next time.